# PHP Error/Exception Handling - hide errors but handle it?

Tags: php, error-handling

I am working on an API server and I'd like to handle all PHP errors and exceptions.
So, when ever I make a request to my API Server, the response will always be consistent - even during a fatal php error or some internal exception from my other class.

I came up with the following:

```
// Register Custom Error Handler
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'logs/php-errors.log');
function ErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    HandleError($errstr, $errfile, $errline);
}
function ExceptionErrorHandler(Exception $e) {
    HandleError($e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
}
function ShutdownFunction() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if (!is_null($error) && sizeof($error)) {
        HandleError($error['message'], $error['file'], $error['line']);
    }
}
function HandleError($message, $file, $line)
{
    // Prepare Error Data
    $error_data = 'File  : '. basename($file)              ."\r\n".
                  'Line  : '. $line                        ."\r\n".
                  'When  : '. date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') ."\r\n".
                  'Error : '. $message;

    // Log Error To File
    $h = fopen('logs/'. date('d-m-Y') .'.log', 'a');
    fwrite($h, $error_data."\r\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n\r\n");
    fclose($h);

    // Exit With Error
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode(array(
        'IsError'  => true,
        'ErrorMsg' => $message .' | '. basename($file) .':'. $line,
        'Data'     => ''
    )));
}
set_error_handler("ErrorHandler");
set_exception_handler('ExceptionErrorHandler');
register_shutdown_function('ShutdownFunction');
```

To test this, on one of my files I called a non existing function called `test()` and this is the response that got produced:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function test() in <b>/home/www-data/public_html/ipos_api/api_methods.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
{"IsError":true,"ErrorMsg":"Call to undefined function test() | api_methods.php:11","Data":""}
```

Why isn't the php error (just above my json response) being hidden? I've set the **display_error** to off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what the problem was.

I am using Nginx with PHP-FPM. On my php-fpm.d pool configuration, I had specified the `display_errors` on, therefore it was over-writing all settings (in-line using ini_set and php.ini itslef).

After removing that config line and re-starting php-fpm, I was able to hide the error message and still handle it.